# passing c pointers through multiple levels of call

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

I am working on a class assignment (which is why only relevant code is being displayed).   I have assigned an array of pointers to an array of random numbers and have to use the bubble sort technique.

The array is set up as follows:

```
int array[DATASIZE] = {71, 1899, 272, 1694, 1697, 296, 722, 12, 2726, 1899};
int *arrayPointers = array; // donation array
```

The function call comes from main and looks is the following:

```
bubbleSort(arrayPointers);
```

I have to do the swapping of the pointers in a separate function :

```
void pointerSwap( int *a , int *b)
{
// swap the pointers and store in a temp
int temp = *a; // temp storage of pointer a while being reassigned
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}// end of pointerSwap
```

from the actual bubble sort:

```
void bubbleSort (int *toStore)
{
//sort each of the pointers successively
int i,j; // counters
for (i=DATASIZE-1;i>1;i--)
    {
    for (j=0;j<DATASIZE-1;j++)
        {
        if (toStore[j]>toStore[j+1])
            {
            pointerSwap(toStore[j],toStore[j+1]);
            }// end of if?
        }// end of j for loop
    }// end of i for loop
}// end of buubleSort
```

My issue is that when I try to compile the code, I get the following errors when I call the pointer swap:

---

**passing argument 1 of ‘pointerSwap’ makes pointer from integer without a cast** 
note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
**passing argument 2 of ‘pointerSwap’ makes pointer from integer without a cast**
note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

---

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly, I have tried "&toStore[j]" and "&toStore[j+1]" but the list sorts the original instead of the pointed array (which is to be expected).

In advance any help is much appreciated, 
~Joey

Comment: but where did you define another storage location to avoid sorting in-place? note: `toStore+j` is clearer for pointers.

Comment: whats with the j in the outer for loop? shouldn't that be an i?

Comment: As you have a function `void bubbleSort (int *toStore)`, which takes only one argument and does not return anything, what else shall the function do than sorting the array passed in place? If you do not want to alter the original array, you somewhere have to copy it. Please provide the code in which you call `bubbleSort`.

Comment: is pointerSwap supposed to swap pointers or swap the values the pointers point at? At the moment it swaps values, the name suggests it should be swapping pointers

Comment: It is supposed to swap the pointers so that the original list remains intact

Answer (score 1):

In the call:

```
pointerSwap(toStore[j],toStore[j+1]);
```

you are passing an `int` (`toStore[j]` is equivelent to `*(toStore + j)`) to a function that expects a pointer. You need to pass a pointer, namely:

```
pointerSwap(toStore + j, toStore + j + 1);
```

The second question pertains to sorting out of place. Your function signiture does not allow for anything else:

```
void bubbleSort (int *toStore)
```

You are not returning anything and you don't give a reference to a second array so you cant do anything but sort in place. If you really need a separate array, you can do something like this:

```
int *bubbleSort (int *input) {
    int* toStore = malloc(DATASIZE * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(toStore, input, DATASIZE);
    ...
    //sort toStore
    ...
    return toStore
}
```

This will then return a sorted array and will not touch the original.

Comment: he said he did "&toStore[j]" and "&toStore[j+1]" - which is the same thing, it compiles but does the wrong thing

Comment: So the code compiles, but when I run the code it still modifies the original arrays instead of the pointed one...

Comment: So still point the array of pointers into the function and then following the above will change the information in the pointer array?

Comment: @Joey It will copy the whole array to a new location. In place sort *that* array, and return it from the function as an `int*`. The original array will not be touched.

Comment: My assignment requires that the second array be an array of pointers to the original and it sorts the values of the original, and the sort is stored in pointer form if that makes any since...

Comment: @Joey well you have not written anything like that. You will need to attempt your own assignment, then ask again here if you have trouble.

Comment: Okay, obviously I was off track, not trying to get work out of you.   Thanks much for the help and I will post back if I have further issues

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the prior answer ...

In C the bracket operator [] is equivalent to *() so that

```
a[5]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(a + 5)
```

Both add an offset to a pointer to get a new pointer and then get the value that's being pointed to.  When you pass in toStore[j] to pointerSwap you are passing the integer value that is in the j-th element of toStore when you want to pass in the pointer so that to Store can swap the values at the locations.

What you want is

```
(toStore + j)
```

instead of

```
*(toStore + j)
```

Fun C trivia:  These are all equivalent expressions

```
toStore[j]
*(toStore + j)
*(j + toStore)
j[toStore]
```

Exercise:  Why is this not true for C++?